# How does a histogram work for the different channels in vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, accelerate-framework

I am attempting to calculate a histogram for the Y channel in a kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange image buffer. When I use vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8 I pass in a reference to only a single histogram.

How do I know which channel is being used to create the histogram? What would I do if I wanted to read all channels?

Also open to critiques of the code sample.

```
extension ViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                       didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        let pixelBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)

//        let format = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer)
//        print("format: \(format)")

        ///kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange = '420v'

        var vBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
        vBuffer.data = pixelBuffer
        vBuffer.rowBytes = bytesPerRow
        vBuffer.width = vImagePixelCount(width)
        vBuffer.height = vImagePixelCount(height)

        let luma = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)

        let lumaHist = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: luma)

        vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8(&vBuffer, lumaHist, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` is a planar format with all the planes encoded into the buffer. And `vImage` planar functions only work on one plane at a time.
The above code is computing an histogram on the three planes but treated as one big plane which is probably not what you want.

It is possible to access the base address and the number of bytes per row for the `Y` plane with these functions:

```
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
let pixelBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
```

The plane index depends of the buffer format. The name usually gives you a hint. Here it's `YpCbCr` so the `Y` plane should be the first one, at index `0`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the header, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress will return:

```
    For chunky buffers, this will return a pointer to the pixel at 
      0,0 in the buffer. 
    For planar buffers this will return a pointer to a PlanarComponentInfo struct 
       (defined in QuickTime).
```

So, if true, it is not computing the histogram of all three channels at once. It is computing the even less useful histogram of the PlanarComponentInfo struct and possibly crashing.

To read all the channels, you can get the second plane out using the interfaces described in Sparga's answer above (CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer,1) and CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer,1)), and do a ARGB histogram of the half width chroma image and add the even histograms together and the odd histograms together. Note that because this is 420, the height and width of the chroma plane is not the same as the luminance plane.

I would also file a bug report with apple asking for vImageHistogramCalculation_RG88 to deal with biplanar chroma data.